# How to write html in a folder?

Tags: html, directory

This must be a stupid question since it's so commonly done.

I've saw an almost all websites which have files (or folders) which display as html code. (In the URL anyway).
Such as [this one](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/).

I have a local website which is later going to be deployed on the web.

Is it another sort of trick (JavaScript, CSS, HTML, PHP, AJAX)? (But I don't think so)

This may have been asked before, I don't know how to phrase the question.

Sorry if it's a stupid question and the bad English.

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Comment: With folder you mean: en-US/firefox/new/ in this case?

Comment: I've saw an almost all websites which have files (or folders) which display as html code. (In the URL anyway). Such as this one.
What do you mean with folder?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.htmlist.com/how-to/a-simplemod_rewrite-tutorial/ - What you see is not a folder structure but a rewritten URL.

Comment: (Please don't update your question to include *responses*. We're not a forum! Thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually most websites do this with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) but you can also create a folder and put a `index.html` in there and just type in the path to the folder in your address bar

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I need to wait 10 minutes to accept as answer.

Comment: If I use the second option, on the address bar will it come like `http://mydomain.com/myfile/` or `http://mydomain.com/myfile/index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this URL ? http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/

in MVC concept, you don't need to create folder, you just need create a function and some parameter to get pretty URL . , or you can use .htaccess